# Java Spring project structure - controllers aren't detected

Tags: java, spring

I'm encountering problems with my Java Spring project structure.

I followed theses three guides from spring.io and i use intellij 2016.3.3 as ide.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

This is a spring boot application and i use annotations in classes.

When all my classes are in the same package - all is working fine but this is very ugly:

```
com.appserver
    - MvcConfiguration.java
    - WebSecurityConfiguration.java
    - GreetingController.java
    - LoginController.java
    - Greeting.java
    - Application.java (main classe)
```

I can see it in the java spring log.

But when I start to use another structure:

```
com.appserver
    - Application.java (main classe)
    config
         - MvcConfiguration.java
         - WebSecurityConfiguration.java
    controller
         - GreetingController.java
         - LoginController.java
    domain
         - Greeting.java
```

It doesn't work. Security configuration and controllers aren't detected.

I tried to use `@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.appserver")` but I'm not sure at all for what I have to do.

Comment: Any exceptions 404 ? or what exactly happens?

Comment: no exception, all configuration is just ignored.I only get a basic auth window.

Comment: What is the basic entry point? Is this a Spring Boot application? If not how is the Application annotated?

Comment: yes this is a spring boot application , and application use the java annotations in class

Comment: Add @RestController annotation to your controller class

Comment: @surya already done but nothing changes.I followed guides on spring.io.

Comment: Ok add @EnableAutoConfiguration in your Application.java ..

Comment: And your controller does not seem to be loaded because you did not mention its  package name in component scan base package (in Application.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now there is no package `com.appserver` in `src/main/java` according to the repository. One option might be to move your source to `src/main/java/com/appserver`.